# JSoup parsing html and create new html

Tags: java, html, parsing, html-parsing, jsoup

I have a static html template with div's of text areas. And then I have a dynamic html with div tags. I need to read all the properties/style of the dynamic html and replace it with same named tagged div's in the static html template to generate a new template.

So the data source for the static template is a dynamic template. Any suggestions how I can do this?

Comment: You're generating the dynamic html with javascript, right?

Comment: that's right. And I have predefined static html in which this dynamic html's data needs to go into...

Comment: It can't be done in JSoup. Try HtmlUnit. See the duplicate.